# Cloning a directory in terminal, using ZSH

Tags: terminal, filesystem, big-sur, zsh

I'm trying to clone a directory which holds a git repo.

i.e., I have `/Users/me/someFolder` - `someFolder` has ALOT of files, like over 250k.
It's also a git repo, with a `.git` directory, and many other hidden files.

Additionally it contains a number of other sub-directories (folders).

So, to clone this, preserving all permissions, copying recursively, and including ALL files/directories in `ZSH` on `Big Sur`, do I simply do:

`cp -a /Users/me/someFolder /Users/me/otherFolder`?

I ask as I've seen other syntax such as:

`cp -a /Users/me/someFolder/. /Users/me/otherFolder`? (note the `.`).

Thanks,

Comment: What's the difference between Zsh and Bash, or any other shell in this particular case ? Both cp and rsync are not a shell builtin in either of the shells. Both of them are commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second method also works if `otherFolder` already exists. Other than that, there is no difference (assuming that `/Users/me/someFolder` is an existing folder). In more detail:

> ```
> cp -a /Users/me/someFolder /Users/me/otherFolder
> ```

If `someFolder` is a folder (i.e. a directory — and not a symbolic link to a directory) and `otherFolder` already exists (and is a directory or a symbolic link to one), this copies `/Users/me/someFolder/some/file` to `/Users/me/otherFolder/someFolder/some/file`. If `someFolder` is a directory but `otherFolder` doesn't exist, this copies `/Users/me/someFolder/some/file` to `/Users/me/otherFolder/some/file`.

If `someFolder` exists but is not a directory (it's a regular file, a symbolic link, etc.), it is copied to either `/Users/me/otherFolder/someFolder` if `otherFolder` is an existing directory or a symbolic link to one, or to `/Users/me/someFolder` otherwise (regular file, other special file, or non-existent).

> ```
> cp -a /Users/me/someFolder/. /Users/me/otherFolder
> ```

If `someFolder` is a directory or a symbolic link to one, this always copies `/Users/me/someFolder/some/file` to `/Users/me/otherFolder/some/file`, regardless of whether `otherFolder` existed or not. (Except if `otherFolder` is an existing file that isn't a symbolic link or a file, in which case the command will fail.)

In all cases, if the thing to copy is a directory, all of its contents are copied recursively, preserving permissions and modification times. (Access times are also preserved, but they're updated in the source.) That comes from the `-a` option.

An equivalent command is

```
rsync -a /Users/me/someFolder/ /Users/me/otherFolder
```

Note the trailing `/` on the source so that `/Users/me/someFolder/some/file` is copied to `/Users/me/otherFolder/some/file`. If the source was `/Users/me/someFolder`, it would be copied to `/Users/me/otherFolder/someFolder`.

`rsync` is equivalent to `cp -R` in simple cases, but it's cleverer about not copying files that are already present in the destination folder, so it's good for resuming an interrupted copy or for doing incremental backups. Rsync also has a lot of options to do things like select which files to copy.

Answer (score 0):

The first option will create something like /Users/me/otherFolder/someFolder, while the second option will leave /Users/me/otherFolder with the contents of someFolder, but not with otherFolder as a subfolder.

Comment: Hi, I think you've misread, the first option doesn't do that. It seems to clone correctly, despite the internet suggesting the syntax is incomplete, in that it should have the extra `.` of the second command I showed.